# Как правильно обособить запятыми в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Какой вариант расстановки пунктуации в данном случае будет правильным?

1. В процессе самостоятельного изучения теоретической физики посредством чтения книг и изучения различных образовательных  материалов моя заинтересованность  данной областью лишь возросла.
2. В процессе самостоятельного изучения теоретической физики,посредством чтения книг и изучения различных образовательных  материалов, моя заинтересованность данной областью лишь возросла.
3. В процессе самостоятельного изучения теоретической физики посредством чтения книг и изучения различных образовательных  материалов, моя заинтересованность данной областью лишь возросла.

Answer (score 1):

Остановитесь на варианте 3:

***В процессе самостоятельного изучения теоретической физики посредством чтения книг и изучения различных образовательных материалов***, моя заинтересованность данной областью лишь возросла.

Пояснение

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов считается **факультативным**, что следует из правил Розенталя.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

В приведенном варинте с помощью запятой мы делим предложение на **две** взаимообусловленные ситуации по следующему образцу: ***Когда*** я  стал изучать физику самостоятельно с помощью книг и других материалов, **то** моя заинтересованность этим предметом еще более возросла.

Comment: Ваш вопрос о "прежде чем" сопоставим с другими союзами: *Я думаю, когда решаю задачу. Я отвечу, как обдумаю всё. Я отвечу, после того как подумаю. Я думаю, пока молчу. Я говорю, как думаю. Я думаю, если отвечаю. Я думаю, потому что отвечаю на сложный вопрос.* (И полно других.)

Comment: Вы разобрались с "прежде чем"? Грамота ответила?

Comment: О oleedd, я не понимаю, что вы хотите? Грамота мне ничего не ответила, в том числе про "прежде чем".